# Use Apple time machine to move from Macbook pro to Macbook air, BUT! TM image > Macbook Air Harddrive

Tags: time-machine, macbook-pro, macbook-air

I want to move my 190GB Macbook Pro time machine image to my new macbook air, but my Macbook Air only has 128GB of storage.

I don't want/need to move all of my files, just all of the installed programs.  Is there a way to specify this?  I want to get all the installed applications/configurations into the new computer and leave out a lot of the other documents and such that are taking up storage.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Macbook Pro is still functioning just fine, you should be able to modify the options in Time Machine to exclude things you don't need and take another backup, or you should be able to go into the Time Machine backup when the drive is connected to the Air and restore what you need.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you run Migration Assistant on the MacBook Air and point it at your Time Machine backup, you should have the option of excluding user directories and extraneous files.

What are you doing to move the image to the new MacBook? You must realize that doing a hard drive clone in Disk Utility is entirely the wrong approach, yes?